# how to mimic Control-Click (multiple selection) of divs with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have rows of divs and I need to multi-select different rows ...but w/o using checkboxes. My rows "highlight" on hover , and gets permanent highlighting when selected w/ this function:

```
function load_to_que(elemID){
    is_selected = $(elemID).attr('is_selected')
    console.log(is_selected);
    if(is_selected != "true"){
        $(elemID).attr('is_selected','true');
        $(elemID).attr('style','background-color: #88C4FF;');
    }else{
        $(elemID).attr('is_selected','false');
        $(elemID).attr('style','');
    }

    //etc....
}
```

w/ the above code i can select and unselect div/rows by clicking, and see visual feedback ... click once, and the div is highlighted, click again and it's background is back to normal.. click on different divs/rows once and you have multiple selections/highlights..

Now what i need to do is...

When clicking on a different div, all the rest of the divs should go back to normal (not highlighted) .. i have 2 ways to do this
 1.1) loop through the elements and evaluate if already selected iva the is_selected attribute, then unselect
 1.2) create a window.selectedIDs variable and maintain a record of selected divs there, and use that to loop through and unselect all currently selected divs

question: w/c is better of the above? or are there are better techniques?

PS
I don't need code detailed examples.. i basically just need good ideas to go about this..

Comment: Man, use a class "is-selected" to change the style of the rows and ditch that attribute. You can then check for the class, and query for the class. Much simpler.

Comment: thanks for the idea, but not applicable for me man.. (i actually use the selected class technique already in other parts of my software) .... the div im trying to highlight here is already using a class .. and i can't use 2 classes on 1 div, nor do i find it efficient to create a whole copy of a complicated class used in the said div, and just have the bg color changed .. so i see this as a more simple approach really.

Comment: You can't use 2 classes on a div? And why?

Comment: @maxart sorry i got a bit confused, i was thinking for my ID situations, can't use 2 ID's in one div.. anyway i get your point re styling method, and doing a direct selection/filtering approach. tnx